# Low open rate of Email despite good IP Warming response & good open rates in the initial months

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, ip-warming

**Problem statement:** Open rates for a new customer via Journey builder tool has gone down after a good start for the initial 2 months and it needs to be rectified. This campaign is for good/reliable customers and not external leads/prospects

**Details**: We have initiated the IP warming for a new Org with around 100,000+ emails via Journey builder[with incremental approach] and it had a good open rate of upwards of 20%. It went for a duration of 5-6 weeks. Post that we initiated real Journey for our customers and the open rates were encouraging for the first 2 months i.e upwards of 30%. Emails sends were 200,000+ for the first month[in 3 shots]. But post-second month onwards, the open rates went down even though the emails send was around 100,000.

Any ideas as to what went wrong from the SFMC perspective? And how to correct it to increase the open rates?

Thanks

Comment: How much did the open rates go down? To 25% or 5%? Did you check your block bounces? Sender Score? Blacklists?

Comment: Unique open rates came down to 7-10. Bounce rate is less than 1%. The Delivery rate is >99%

Comment: Can you check open rates by recipient domain? It will show you which ISPs show bad performance, as this rarely is an overall MC issue. This will help you to focus on the ISPs which have low inbox placements. Also do check the other points I mentioned in above comment ([sender score](https://senderscore.org/) and [blacklists](https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx))

Comment: Let me check it via ISPs wise. Also, I m trying to figure out the how-to check (sender score and blacklists. Another observation, if the sends are less in no., then open rate is higher and vice versa

Comment: The sender score is 98% and blacklists report is also positive. How to view domain wise report for a journey?

Comment: Go to Analytics Builder > Reports, and click on Email under Report Catalog. Scroll to "Email Performance for All Domains", and click Create. Select the email you want to report on. Select the right Email Threshold (I tend to use 10), Time Zone and Culture Code, and click Submit. Click on the download icon (downward arrow):

Comment: I was aware of it but not sure how to get the emails sends for a specific journey.

Comment: You can look up the job ID under Email Studio > Tracking > Sends > Journey Builder Sends. Use this to find the right email in reporting.